# conditional guard clauses in elixir

Tags: elixir

Is there any way to use `or` or `and` expressions in function guard clauses:

```
defmodule Test do
   def testfn(arg1, arg2) when is_nil(arg1) || is_nil(arg2), do: :nothing

   def testfn2(arg1, arg2) when is_nil(arg1) && is_nil(arg2), do: :nothing
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guard expressions do not support `&&` and `||` (which accept any value on the LHS), but only `and` and `or` (which accepts only booleans on the LHS). Since `is_nil` always returns a boolean, you can switch to using `and` and `or`:

```
defmodule Test do
   def testfn(arg1, arg2) when is_nil(arg1) or is_nil(arg2), do: :nothing

   def testfn2(arg1, arg2) when is_nil(arg1) and is_nil(arg2), do: :nothing
end
```

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html contains a list of all functions/operators allowed in guards.